# R: subset a matrix of unknown length using a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, subset

I am using values in one matrix (data1) to determine how to subset a second matrix (data2) into a smaller matrix (foo).  However I am running into problems as I have no way of knowing ahead of time the size of foo.

Here is a MWE (the actual data structs in question are 100,000+ rows long).

```
data1 <- rbind(c(102,250,'stim1'),c(477,839,'stim2'))
data2 <- rbind(c(99,'xx'),c(105,'yy'),c(230,'zz'),c(312,'aa'),c(587,'bb'),c(846,'cc'))

foo <- NULL
for(i in 1:nrow(data1))
{   
        foo[i,1] <- subset(data2,as.numeric(data2[,1]) > as.numeric(data1[i,1]) & as.numeric(data2[,1]) < as.numeric(data1[i,2]))
        foo[i,2] <- rep.int(data1[i,3],nrow(subset(data2,as.numeric(data2[,1]) > as.numeric(data1[i,1]) & as.numeric(data2[,1]) < as.numeric(data1[i,2]))))
}
```

I would like foo to look like this:

```
105 yy stim1
230 zz stim1
587 bb stim2
```

Comment: For a start, don't use matrices if your data contains more than one type of data, here integers and characters. You need to use data.frames.

Comment: Sorry, the original is a data frame... I just failed to do that for the MWE.

Comment: There's a few problems here: (1) `data1` and `data2` should be data frames so that numeric columns can be numeric and not character. (2) Your function that assigns `foo[i,1]` returns a matrix, but `foo[i,1]` is a single value. My suggestion is that `foo` should be a `list` of matrices, not a matrix. That way you don't need to know how big it is, anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, put what you have in a `data.frame`.

```
data1 <- data.frame(A=c(102, 477), B=c(250, 839), C=c("stim1", "stim2"))
data2 <- data.frame(a=c(99, 105, 230, 312, 587, 846), 
                     b=c("xx", "yy", "zz", "aa", "bb", "cc"))
```

Then you can use apply:

```
List <- apply(data1, 1, function(X) 
                     cbind(data2, c=X[[3]])[data2$a > X[1] & data2$a < X[2],])
```

Then `rbind` the `list`:

```
DF <- do.call(rbind, List)
DF

    a  b     c
2 105 yy stim1
3 230 zz stim1
5 587 bb stim2
```